# I would like to insert the result into a table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query is as below :

```
Declare @FromDate date = '2015-April-1';            

With finYears(finY) as (
    Select DATEADD(month, UsesrID, @FromDate) 
    From (values(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) 
    as x(UsesrID)

)

Select * From (
    Select e.UserID, name = left(DATENAME(month, f.finY), 3), t.Amount   
    From finYears f
    Cross Join (Select distinct UserID From UserProfile) as e
    Cross Apply (Select MAX(CreatedDate) From EmployeeBasicSalary x 
    Where x.CreatedDate <= f.finY and x.UserID = e.UserID) mx(maxYear) 
    right outer Join EmployeeBasicSalary t on t.UserID = e.UserID and t.CreatedDate = mx.maxYear
) as p

Pivot(
    sum(Amount)
    for name in ([Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar])
) as piv
```

I want to insert the result into Monthly Salary Table

Output:

```
    UserID  TotalAmount   April   May      June      July    Aug       Sep        Oct     Nov    Dec        Jan        Feb       March 
     001          13200    1000    1000      1000      1000  1000       1000        1200  1200    1200       1200        1200     1200    
002         16800     1100    1100      1100      1500  1500       1500        1500  1500     1500      1500        1500     1500    
003         21000     1400    1400      1400      1700  1700       1700         1700  2000    2000       2000        2000     2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is for Microsoft SQL Server (based on the SQL being used), you should be to simply add the `INSERT` statement just before the `SELECT` as follows:

```sql
...
)
INSERT INTO dbo.MonthlySalary (UserID, TotalAmount,
                               April, May, June, July, Aug, Sep,
                               Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, March)
Select * From (
    Select e.UserID, name = left(DATENAME(month, f.finY), 3), t.Amount  
...
```